# QoS or something else?

Tags: windows, bandwidth, qos

When running a bit-torrent client I find that it uses all my available ports(right term?), such that I can't surf the internet or get any response from web apps. This is not a bandwidth issue as I have 15Mbps and even if only a fraction of that is in use from uTorrent, this problem will still happen if I'm connected to enough peers. I know about the bandwidth and connection # caps in uTorrent, but I don't want these set low all the time, and the connection # seems to need to be really low to get the browser to work.

I've read a little about QoS and dd-wrt but is that the best solution for this, or is there a windows software solution? I basically just want uTorrent to take a back seat to anything else (browser, netflix, xbox, etc.)

Any ideas?